# Migrate from Glassfish with EJB to Google App Engine with Spring

Tags: java, google-app-engine, migration, glassfish, ejb

I have a pretty big project written in Java using EJB 3 + Hibernate and it is hosted on Glassfish server. Now want to rewrite everything and move it to Google App Engine. What would be the easiest way to do it. Should we start using Spring in order to create entities to manage data?
The reason why we want to move away from EJB + Hibernate is the cpu overhead and the development. It takes up to 10 min sometimes to restart the server to test the changes.
We are using GWT for the front end.

Answer (score 5):

Before you start such a massive migration, maybe keep in mind that you could improve startup performance by not using annotations and listing your entities and ejb beans in XML. Make sure to switch off annotation scanning. Personally I would rather trade of startup speed for the development convenience of not having to maintain verbose XML files, but maybe this is helpful to you.

You can also opt to start using JRebel. This will greatly reduce the number of required restarts during development (in most cases reduce them to zero).

If it's just about moving to the cloud, you don't have to rewrite to Spring either. There are various offerings that support EJBs and general Java EE ears just fine (e.g. OpenShift). GAE may be cool, but it's hard to totally stay away from the GAE APIs. Once you start using these, you're pretty much locked into GAE.

As a personal note, I think migrating to Spring from EJB is backwards, the trend seems to be strongly the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

If the project becomes really large, then Spring will start up slowely as well. The more beans you have, the slower startup becomes.

Although we have projects with some couple of hundreds EJB beans, and startup time is okay (30 to 40 seconds). I assisted a while back on a Spring project which I guessed was approximately the same size, but it took a few minutes to start.

So before you spend 2 years rewriting everything using a completely different framework, I highly advise you to do some benchmarking of your own first.

Perhaps just spending some money on adequate hardware is the more economical solution. Fast SSDs, enough memory and a reasonbly fast CPU do wonders.

If it's just about the development experience, this doesn't have to cost much for a workstation. I'm not advocating just throwing hardware at a problem, but doing a major rewrite to a completely different tech in order to improve startup speed for which you can't even be sure will actually improve, might simply not be the smartest thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 live Spring project on GAE, and can recommend it.

It's flexble, and fast enough: startup takes 15-20 seconds (on GAE), and processing a request about 60-90ms (w/o GAE API calls).

Of course, you can use plan servlets, but it will be too hard to mantain.